# SqlDependency in MVC 6 on DNX Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, sql-server-2014, sqldependency

I need to build app with real-time SQL Server notifications (DB will be updated from external app).
I use ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6). I want to use SqlDependency but it is unavailable in DNX Core 5.0 and I get an error:

```
CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SqlDependency' could not be found (are you 
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What can I do to use SqlDependency in MVC 6.

Comment: Do you use DNX Core because want to run your app on Mac/Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on running it on windows, you can just remove DNX Core and just use dnx46.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx46": {}
}
```

Comment: Where did you hook up the event, usually you put it in Application_Start, but asp.net mvc 6 doesn't have this event?

 //Start SqlDependency with application initialization
 SqlDependency.Start(connString);